# Operator norm: Show that $\|A\|=\sup\{ |f(Ax)| : x \in X, \|x\| \leq 1 , f \in Y^*, \|f\| \leq 1 \}$

Tags: general-topology, operator-theory, normed-spaces

Good day,

As stated in the title, I have to show that
$\|A\|=\sup\{ |f(Ax)| : x \in X, \|x\|_X \leq 1 , f \in Y^*, \|f\| \leq 1 \}$

where

- $\| \cdot \|$ is the operator norm, i.e. for $X,Y$ vector spaces and $T \in L(X,Y)=\{T:X \to Y : T ~\text{linear} \}$ it is defined by $$||T||:=\sup_{x \in X \backslash\{0 \}} \|Tx\| / \|x\|=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\| = \sup_{\|x\| = 1} ||Tx||$$
- Here: $A \in B(X,Y):=\{ A \in L(X,Y) ~|~ \exists M< \infty ~\forall x \in X : ||Ax|| \leq M ||x|| \}$ for $X,Y$ normed spaces
- $f \in Y^* := B(Y,\mathbb{R} )$ the topological dual space to Y

Show: $$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1, \|f\| \leq 1} |f(Ax)|$$

By definition $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|Ax\|$ and $\|f\|=\sup_{\|Ax\|=1} |f(Ax)|$ and it doesn't look so far away from what we want to prove, should work pretty straight forward I think. $A$ and $f$ are each in a bounded space, i.e. for $M,K < \infty$
$$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} \|Ax\| \leq \sup_{\|x\| \leq 1} M \|x\|=M ~\text{and}~ \|f\| \leq K$$

But from here I can't see the proof. Can someone help me please?

Thanks a lot,
Marvin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By definition $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \|Ax\|$, and by Hahn-Banach theorem we can show $\forall y\in Y, \|y\|=\sup_{\|f\|\leq 1,f\in Y^*} \|f(y)\|$.

Combining them, we have

$\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|\leq 1} \sup_{\|f\|\leq 1,f\in Y^*} \|f(Ax)\|$, which is what you want.

Comment: Gosh, I totally forgot about Hahn-Banach. Thanks a lot, good answer.